# Get Pandrive or USB Serial Number Using Java

Tags: java, security, usb, system

I need to copy protect my software so I need to get serial number of a USB or pendrive so, how can find serial number of pendrive for protection. If there are any other way to protect it please share with me.

Comment: What exactly do you want to protect?

Comment: #codeMan, the software should run in pandrive if anybody want to copy and paste it in another device the software show the error.

Comment: There is no practical way to completely protect your code, except for making sure nobody gets to your code. Have them register using a UI app you distribute, but that connects to a webservice on a server you host.
usb sticks can be swapped, so simply looking at that isn't that safe nether.